# How to make Touch Accommodations & simultaneousGesture features work together

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

We have an icon in the login page in SwiftUI application. On icon, using simultaneousGesture of tap gesture count 3 and long press gesture shows a different view. This works fine until Touch Accommodations toggle button turned ON with Hold Duration set to 2 secs.
.accessibilityHidden(true) modifier for Image is not working.
Is there a way to skip Touch Accommodation feature for one UI element in a SwiftUI view?

Also application uses CoreBluetooth framework to pair & sync BLE peripherals. While pairing app shows text box to enter code displayed on the BLE peripheral to pair the peripheral with the application. With Touch Accommodations toggle button turned ON and Hold Duration set to 2 secs, pin text box disappears before entering all the code digits, so BLE peripheral pairing is failed. (Similar issue with AVPlayer controls. Controls disappears with Touch Accommodation feature ON & Hold Duration set to 4 secs. Not able to play/pause/close.)
Is there a way to skip Touch Accommodation feature on keypad to enter code before pairing code text box disappear?

Edited: Link to use Touch Accommodations:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205269

Source code for simultaneousGesture feature:

```
image.simultaneousGesture(LongPressGesture(minimumDuration:1).onEnded { _ in
})
.highPriorityGesture(TapGesture(count: 3).onEnded { _ in
})
```

Comment: Can you include some sample picture or video or something because this is a plain text, so I can’t recreate anything relates to your problem.

Comment: Usage of simultaneousGesture is updated.